# Skip Chromecast selection when sending from Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast-sdk

I'm trying to send data to a chromecast, but I would like to send the data to a certain Chromecast directly, without selecting it in the Google Chrome.

**I would like to skip the Chromecast selection before sending data.**

This is want to avoid.

[image]

I dont want to select the cast but directly cast the data to it.

I've been checking the `session` object that we get from `chrome.cast.initialize` and it return something like this:

```
      {
        "sessionId": "b59f1754-fd13-48cd-b237-4952a69cade4",
        "appId": "5B797F56",
        "displayName": "url-cast-sender",
        "statusText": "URL Cast ready...",
        "receiver": {
          "label": "rTflOUigItAIYPwoZZ87Uv5oK8yI.",
          "friendlyName": "Sala de Juntas",
          "capabilities": [
            "video_out",
            "audio_out"
          ],
          "volume": {
            "controlType": "attenuation",
            "level": 1,
            "muted": false,
            "stepInterval": 0.05000000074505806
          },
          "receiverType": "cast",
          "isActiveInput": null,
          "displayStatus": null
        },
        "senderApps": [],
        "namespaces": [
          {
            "name": "urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.debugoverlay"
          },
          {
            "name": "urn:x-cast:com.url.cast"
          }
        ],
        "media": [],
        "status": "connected",
        "transportId": "b59f1754-fd13-48cd-b237-4952a69cade4"
      };
```

As you can see there is `label` there, I've been trying to work with it but nothing.

The way the page request the connection to a chromecast is the following:

```
// click handlers
document.getElementById('requestSession').onclick = function () {
  chrome.cast.requestSession(sessionListener, onErr);
};
```

Which seems to be the part that opens the selection alert in Google Chrome.

**My work is a fork from [url-cast-receiver](https://github.com/DeMille/url-cast-receiver) and you can check a demo [here](https://demille.github.io/url-cast-receiver/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is not possible from the frontend part.

So I ended up using a library called **[SharpCaster](https://github.com/Tapanila/SharpCaster)** created by **[Tapanila](https://github.com/Tapanila)**, in which there is a controller that allows you to do this kind of stuff, **[here](https://github.com/Tapanila/SharpCaster/blob/master/SharpCaster.Test/WebPageCastingTester.cs)** you can find an example of it.

Had some trouble to make it work and also opened an issue in the repository, but ended up fixing it myself, **[issue #141](https://github.com/Tapanila/SharpCaster/issues/141)**.

**[WebPageCastingTester.cs](https://github.com/Tapanila/SharpCaster/blob/master/SharpCaster.Test/WebPageCastingTester.cs)**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SharpCaster.Controllers;
using SharpCaster.Services;
using Xunit;

namespace SharpCaster.Test
{
    public class WebPageCastingTester
    {
        private ChromecastService _chromecastService;
        public WebPageCastingTester()
        {
            _chromecastService = ChromecastService.Current;
            var device = _chromecastService.StartLocatingDevices().Result;
            _chromecastService.ConnectToChromecast(device.First()).Wait(2000);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void TestingLaunchingSharpCasterDemo()
        {
            var controller =  await _chromecastService.ChromeCastClient.LaunchWeb();
            await Task.Delay(4000);
            Assert.NotNull(_chromecastService.ChromeCastClient.ChromecastStatus.Applications.First(x => x.AppId == WebController.WebAppId));
            await controller.LoadUrl("https://www.windytv.com/");
            await Task.Delay(4000);
            Assert.Equal(_chromecastService.ChromeCastClient.ChromecastStatus.Applications.First(x => x.AppId == WebController.WebAppId).StatusText,
                "Now Playing: https://www.windytv.com/");
        }
    }
}
```